# TypeError: on_ready() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot but the on_ready always gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_ready() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Here's my code

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print("Connected")
   await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=" for *help"))
```

It used to work before but now it doesn't, Why?

Comment: Is your code inside a cog file?

Comment: No it isn't in a cog file

Comment: Is it inside a class?

Comment: no it isn't inside a class

Comment: So why did you put the `self` parameter?

Comment: I tried taking it out but still same error

Comment: `on_ready` event takes no parameter, do you have any now?

Comment: i took out all parameters but same error

Answer (score -1):

What happens if you delete the `self` argument?

As far as i know you only put the `self` argument when the function is defined within an class object. So rather delete it or rewrite/extend your code to a class object function.